# Getting started with neo4j

Tags: nosql, neo4j

I am completely new to neo4j and I am very sorry for asking such a basic question. I have installed neo4j, I am using the shell "localhost:7474/webadmin/#/console/" 
I am looking for a good example that uses some shell commands to read from a pre-existing graph database, traverse, modify,... it and then perform some queries in order to learn it. I don't want to use any Java or Python, all I want is some command line examples that will allow me to learn neo4j.
I searched a lot but could not find a good sample code except one matrix example.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the virtues of [Neo4J](http://www.neo4j.org/) is the excellent documentation and learning material it provides (especially compared to other Graph enabled DBs).

As mentioned, starting with [The Cypher Tutorial](http://www.neo4j.org/learn/cypher) is a good starting point.

Then, as you learn the basics, check out [The Neo4J Manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/) which has detailed documentation on each and every Cypher language command (as well as many other interesting stuff).

Finally, when you start doing your own queries, keep close a copy of the [Cypher Cheat Sheet](http://neo4j.org/resources/cypher) which summarizes all the commands.

You can even take a look at Cypher without installing or running Neo4J server, just going to the [Neo4J Console](http://console.neo4j.org/) and test your queries online (and even create links to them).

Caveat: when you start reading you may encounter with [Gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki), which is a common graph query language supported by Neo4J. Is quite awkward and very different from Cypher, so if you are going with Neo4J, you should stick to Cypher, it has more features and most of the development is made against it.

Answer (score 1):

Cypher is your friend (there are several samples on this page):
http://www.neo4j.org/learn/cypher

Check out the Cypher-specific webinars:
http://watch.neo4j.org/

And finally, the Cypher cheatsheet:
http://neo4j.org/resources/cypher