# Neo4J getting started

Tags: database, neo4j

I just downloaded Neo4J. I am totally new to it.  I read the concept of graph data bases and I am really looking forward to use it. Can some one please tell me how to make my own database using cypher? I went through the syntax of the query language. But where exactly am i supposed to type the code?
Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16524702/1175077) to a similar question.